# How to use differential equation to solve simple school problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, python

There is simple school programming problem:

> If I were on the moon now then my weight would be equals to `my_weight * 0.165`.
> Suppose each year of `n` years my weight grows to `0.4 kg`. Thus, I should calculate my weight on moon
> for each month of there number of years.

I solve the problem with python like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
float_formatter = "{:.2f}".format

current_weight = int(input("Enter your current weight: "))
months_weight_rate = float(input("Enter years rate of grows: ")) / 12
months = int(input("Enter number of years: ")) * 12

months_weights = []

for i in range(1, months + 1, 1):
    months_weights.append(float(float_formatter(((current_weight + months_weight_rate) * 0.165))))
    current_weight += months_weight_rate

print(*months_weights)

plt.plot(np.arange(1, months + 1, 1), months_weights)
plt.show()
```

and have output like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3trSY.jpg

My general question is can I use differential equation to solve the problem?

After some search I find out the paper [http://math.smith.edu/~callahan/cic/ch4.pdf](http://math.smith.edu/%7Ecallahan/cic/ch4.pdf)
on the page 3 where is considered diff equation to solve rabbits growth rate problem.

It looks like what I need. But I can't find out how to adapt this equation to solve my problem.

Comment: You mean like $\frac{d({\rm weight})}{dt}=\frac{0.4~{\rm kg}}{\rm 1~ year}$?

Comment: Differential equations are useful when the change in our dependent variable (for example, number of new born rabbits each year) is a function of the dependent variable (number of rabbits, because they will make babies). In your example, the change in weight is not a function of weight, rather, it is a fixed amount each year. In this case differential equations are not useful.